# blog and its author and commenter [how to make them appear]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have 3 models , `user has many articles` , `user has many comments` , `articles belongs to user` , `comments belongs to user` , how to make the name of the user appear in the comment or in the article when he post it ?

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
  <p><strong><%=  %> says</strong></p> # how should i write a condition here to make the name of the commenter appear when he puts a comment
  <%= simple_format comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add that a `Comment` belongs to `User` as well.

and then: `<%= comment.user.name %>` ( in case user model has name attribute )

Comment: undefined method `user_name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%= div_for comment do %>
2:   <p><strong><%= comment.user.user_name %> says</strong></p>
3:   <%= simple_format comment.content %>
4: <% end %>

Comment: I don't have enough info. Paste in your Comment and User model

Comment: i have found it, just was missing `@comment.user_id = current_user.id` in the controller, and i did that also for the articles and thanks for your help :D